# Raspberry Pi Raspbian Upgrade

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Recently Raspbian Stretch has been released. Is there any harm in upgrading from Jessie? PS: Kodi is gonna get uninstalled if I upgrade, it's a wanted app for me.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience with Debian (on which Raspbian is based upon), it's easier to reinstall the whole OS in the version you want (in your case Stretch/Testing).

The issue with upgrading from a "Stable" release to a "Testing" release is, that all dependencies are upgraded as well.
Some will be removed as they are merged into other packages, new ones appear for features in the testing versions of packages and in turn applications that depend on the removed packages are removed as well.

Long story short: backup your configuration files and home directory and do a clean installation.

Comment: Ok. But that too needs a backup, I will try to emulate a Debian environment and upgrade. If anything gets wrong, I can follow your instructions.